# Exception when restarting embedded activeMQ broker with jdbcPersistenceAdapter

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

Using ActiveMQ 5.9.0, I have the following broker configuration:

```
<amq:broker id="broker" useShutdownHook="false" persistent="true">
    <amq:persistenceAdapter>
        <amq:jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#dataSource">
        </amq:jdbcPersistenceAdapter>
    </amq:persistenceAdapter>
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="${broker.url}" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>
```

If there are already messages in the database when the broker is started, I get the exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.activemq.command.WireFormatInfo cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.activemq.command.Message   at
>   org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.getLastMessageBrokerSequenceId(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.region.DestinationFactoryImpl.getLastMessageBrokerSequenceId(DestinationFactoryImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.(RegionBroker.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedRegionBroker.(ManagedRegionBroker.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.createRegionBroker(BrokerService.java:2172)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.createRegionBroker(BrokerService.java:2165)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.createBroker(BrokerService.java:2122)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.getBroker(BrokerService.java:906)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.getAdminConnectionContext(BrokerService.java:2393)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startVirtualConsumerDestinations(BrokerService.java:2533)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startDestinations(BrokerService.java:2384)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartBroker(BrokerService.java:640)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startBroker(BrokerService.java:632)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:568)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.autoStart(BrokerService.java:524)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.postConstruct(BrokerService.java:511)

It seems to me that the format used to marshal the message may be different from the one used when unmarshalling. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Were the messages generated from an older ActiveMQ version?

Comment: @TimBish No, it was the same ActiveMQ version. I switched to version 5.5.0 and now it works fine.

Comment: What is your architecture?

Comment: @Leo I'm using an embedded amq over an oracle db. I finally found out what the problem was, it had to do with the oracle drivers I had been using.

Comment: fancy bug :-) good to know you've solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the oracle driver version. When a blob column was read from the database the data got corrupted.
The problem was rather difficult to reproduce (stopping the application while messages were received), so switching to amq 5.5.0 was a false positive. I was using ojdbc 10.1.0.2.0 and switching to ojdbc6 11.2.0.3 solved the problem.